# Sort items by field name

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have many fields which I would like to distinct generically.
Right now, I have to write this for each field:

```
  if (cFieldName == "cEVEN_DAL")
  {
    eventLOGS_DistinctField = eventLogs.DistinctBy(x => x.cEVEN_DAL);
  }
```

What I would like to do is something like:

```
eventLOGS_DistinctField = eventLogs.DistinctBy(myFieldName);
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What datatype is `myFieldName`? It would need to be an `Expression<Func<T1, T2>>`, because that's what `Distinct` is taking.

Comment: you can write your own extension method

Comment: Why library are you using for `DistinctBy`? That method is not part of standard Linq.

Comment: @styx - any example perhaps? I know I can write extension method, but field names would be hardcoded again.

Comment: @gunr2171 - they are all strings. Can you please post some example?

Comment: @gunr2171 Possibly [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)

Comment: @gunr2171 - yes, its MoreLiNQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Test> tests = new List<Test>() //Example objects
        {
            new Test
            {
                A = 1,
                B = 2,
                C = 3,
            },
            new Test
            {
                A = 2,
                B = 2,
                C = 3,
            },
            new Test
            {
                A = 3,
                B = 2,
                C = 3,
            },
            new Test
            {
                A = 1,
                B = 1,
                C = 3,
            },
            new Test
            {
                A = 1,
                B = 2,
                C = 3,
            },
            new Test
            {
                A = 1,
                B = 3,
                C = 3,
            },
            new Test
            {
                A = 1,
                B = 2,
                C = 1,
            },
            new Test
            {
                A = 1,
                B = 2,
                C = 2,
            },
            new Test
            {
                A = 1,
                B = 2,
                C = 3,
            }
        };
        List<Test> results = DistinctBy(tests, "A"); //Use of DistinctBy
    }

    private static List<T> DistinctBy<T>(List<T> objs, string propertyName)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
        return objs.GroupBy(x => property.GetValue(x)).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate an Expression `x => x.cEVEN_DAL` with Linq API:

```
// because you said in comments that all fields are string I'm using Func<T, string> here
public static Expression<Func<T, string>> Create<T>(string fieldName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
    var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, fieldName);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(property, parameter);
}
```

If you are usinq MoreLinq you need to compile this expression:

```
var lambda = Create< TypeOfEventLogItem  >("cEVEN_DAL");
var func = lambda.Compile();
var result = eventLogs.DistinctBy(func);
```